# WUBI dual boot problem

Tags: 16.04

I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 in my Windows 7 PC with Wubi.

After I press the "Reboot Now" button the computer doesn't ask me to choose Ubuntu or Windows 7 and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @karel, no wubi is not virtualization, it does not boot or run within windows. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi .@Alexandru see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu

Comment: You may not see the uefi menu as you boot, you need to hit a key depending on your BIOS (UEFI), see https://www.lifewire.com/wubi-linux-installation-program-2201175 for a list of common keys by hardware vendor

Comment: At the end of the day, better to install a proper dual boot. Wubi was never intended for that and can't give the same performance (in that sense it does behave like or worse than virtualization @Panther but other than that I agree entirely with your assessment and the online resources you provided).